# Redactor adding extra paragraph and br tag when entering and exiting HTML source mode

Tags: redactor, richtext, bug

I'm currently on the latest version of Craft (2.6.2785). When I edit Redactor content I have no issues, but if I enter HTML mode and exit it I end up with `<p><br></p>` prepended to the content.

Here's a GIF of this issue.
[image: Redactor issue with paragraph and br tags]

I updated from version 2.5.2767 and that version does not have this bug.

In case it helps, here's the JSON config for the Redactor field I'm referring to:

```
{
  "buttons": ["html", "formatting", "bold", "italic", "unorderedlist", "orderedlist", "link", "file", "image", "video"],
  "plugins": ["fullscreen", "video", "table"],
  "toolbarFixed": true
}
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, this is definitely a Redactor bug and not something the Craft community can really help with. It's also something we are more than aware of; I have the same bug on a lot of my sites, which is why I have installed Pixel & Tonics Redactor 1 plugin for now: https://github.com/pixelandtonic/RedactorI. We just have to wait for Redactor bug fixes to be released I'm afraid.

Comment: Hey @JamieWade, it looks like Redactor has corrected this issue [in the latest release as of 5/22](https://imperavi.com/redactor/log/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with Redactor itself. Their example allowing you to edit the [source code of a field has the same bug](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/source).

Comment: As of 5/22 this bug has been fixed in Redactor. https://imperavi.com/redactor/log/